# How to build PyCurl on MACOSX 10.11.6 without error

Tags: macos, curl, pycurl

I am trying to build Pycurl against a version of libcurl (7.53.1) without success.

I am on MACOSX El Capitan v10.11.6.

I am not even sure I am aligned with OpenSSL at this point. I may need to make sure OpenSSL is properly installed and get Curl built with OpenSSL. Finally get Pycurl built with the proper Curl.

I have been followed couple of tracks on-line but none of them are getting me where I need to be.

What would be the best option to solve this build issue?

Log:

```
users-MBP-2:~ mickael$ sudo easy_install pycurl 
Password:
Searching for pycurl
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/ Best match: pycurl 7.43.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/12/3f/557356b60d8e59a1cce62ffc07ecc03e4f8a202c86adae34d8958262 81fb/pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz#md5=c94bdba01da6004fa38325e9bd6b9760
Processing pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-tmm5sV/pycurl-7.43.0/setup.cfg
Running pycurl-7.43.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-tmm5sV/pycurl-7.43.0/egg-dist- tmp-Yj_ArM
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.53.1)
warning: no files found matching 'src/Makefile'
In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
In file included from src/pycurl.h:32:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.53.1/include/curl/curl.h:39: /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.53.1/include/curl/curlrules.h:143:6: error: '__curl_rule_01__' declared as an array with a negative
size
[CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.53.1/include/curl/curlrules.h:132:27: note: expanded from macro 'CurlchkszEQ' #define CurlchkszEQ(t, s) sizeof(t) == s ? 1 : -1
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.53.1/include/curl/curlrules.h:153:6: error: '__curl_rule_02__' declared as an array with a negative
size
[CurlchkszEQ(curl_off_t, CURL_SIZEOF_CURL_OFF_T)];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.53.1/include/curl/curlrules.h:132:27: note: expanded from macro 'CurlchkszEQ' #define CurlchkszEQ(t, s) sizeof(t) == s ? 1 : -1
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
src/pycurl.h:190:5: warning: "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine
which " "library was
used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may "
requests" [-W#warnings]
# warning \ ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
"cause random crashes on SSL
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is definitely some challenges to build Pycurl. Here are the steps I took:

1. Make sure OpenSSL was installed (if not use Brew: brew install openssl).
2. Rebuild Curl with OpenSSL, remember Curl is not built with OpenSSL by default on MacOsX/El Capitan, SecureTransport is used instead. (try: brew install --force curl --with-openssl)
3. Rebuild Pycurl with "pip". I had success with pip but not with easy_install. (try: sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install pycurl)

Pycurl is installed under: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycurl.so

Version installed is: pycurl-7.43.0